# AngularJS not sending request after CORS preflight response

Tags: angularjs, http-headers, cors

Using AngularJS to call RESTFUL APIs.

When using Chrome browser on IOS, the CORS preflight request's (OPTIONS request's) `Accept` header gets set to `*/*,image/webp`.  The response comes back fine, but the actual GET request never gets sent. As you can see in the response, the `Content-Type` header gets set to `image/webp`, which I suspect is causing the problem in AngularJS from moving forward with the GET request.

Is my assumption correct? If so, is the solution to force the server to set the `Content-Type` to something else ?

Full request headers:

```
OPTIONS http://www.example.com:8080/resourceABC HTTP/1.1
Host: www.example.com:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, authorization, origin
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://www.example.com
Accept: */*,image/webp
Referer: http://www.example.com/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/600.1.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) CriOS/38.0.2125.67 Mobile/12B411 Safari/600.1.4
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Full response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Allow: GET,OPTIONS,HEAD
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Content-Type, x-requested-with, authorization, accept
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Content-Type: image/webp
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 29 Oct 2014 19:26:37 GMT
```

Comment: I am having this same issue and I have no fix, have you managed to fix this on your end?

Comment: Well, it wasn't clear to me where the bug is, whether it's with Spring or Chromium.  I logged chromium defect 429507 but didn't follow through really.    I ended up working around the problem server side, doing this hack here : (pseudocode)

if (method == "OPTIONS" && header == "Accept") {
                    if (header.contains("image/webp")) {
                        headers.remove("Content-Type");
                        headers.add("Content-Type", "text/plain");
                    }
                }

Answer (score 2):

Hy.
I just had the same thing here accessing a REST-Service on a different domain from AngularJS-Service.

Examining the request-headers sent to my REST-Service to see if I do allow everything that is requested from the client lead mit to the following:

Setting 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' in a way to make sure it contains all items in 'Access-Control-Request-Headers' solved it for me.

Marc I see that in your 'Access-Control-Request-Headers' the header "origin" is requested but in your "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" it's missing.

Sending the following Response-Headers works in my case (*appkey is my internal auth-key in header*):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: appkey,content-type
```

Hope this is clear and it helps.
Best regards,
Christian

P.S.: "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *" did not work in my case

**UPDATE:**

To allow Form-Submit via POST-Request I had to add 'content-type' to 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for the input.  I added `Origin` to `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` but same problem.

In the request, are you seeing `Accept: */*,image/webp`  ? and in your response, are you seeing `Content-Type: image/webp` ?   I really think this is related to the problem.

Comment: I've made some progress.  This is unrelated to angularJS, I can reproduce with a simple AJAX request.  I can get around the issue by forcing the server to return `Content-Type: text/plain` for the `OPTIONS` response only. This is a hack, so I have to understand why without this hack it returns `Content-Type: image/webp`.   Either way, there is a bug somewhere, why is CHROME setting this `Accept` header value for a OPTIONS request ??? makes no sense.

Comment: Hy Marc. Today I was able to test my service with Chrome on iPAD and it does say `accept :*/*,image/webp` in the request.
My response always says `Content-Type: text/plain` so your issue does not pop up here. I do not set it by hand - it seems to be a default (pretty old tomcat6). I'm wondering why your framework returns `image/webp` when `*/*` is accapted too.
I did a little investigation but was not able to find out what the correct content-type of a CORS-preflight-response should be according to the specification. In the examples i always read `text/plain`.

Comment: I'm using a Spring Framework backend, so I'll have to debug to see why it's setting the Content-Type to that. I also have issue 429507 opened with Chromium, although I'm not sure who's bug this is yet.  Thanks Christian